# Issues installing Tk module via Cpan

Tags: macos, perl, tk-toolkit, cpan

I am trying to set up a text analysis software that requires a working version of the perl module Tk on mac os.
However I can't install it through CPAN for some reason.
I proceed by typing

```
sudo perl -MCPAN -e "shell"
```

then

```
install Tk
```

It runs the make install process and ends with this error

```
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all-am'.
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `test_dynamic'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [subdirs-test_dynamic] Error 2
make: *** [subdirs-test_dynamic] Error 2
  SREZIC/Tk-804.033.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make test -- NOT OK
//hint// to see the cpan-testers results for installing this module, try:
  reports SREZIC/Tk-804.033.tar.gz
Running make install
  make test had returned bad status, won't install without force
```

Any clue on how I could workaround this issue?
I am not quite familiar with perl so I'm really fumbling around here...
Any help would be very much appreciated.
Thanks !

**UPDATE**

When trying to install the module manually, the make test command gives me this outcome:

```
"/usr/bin/perl" -MExtUtils::Command::MM -e 'cp_nonempty' -- Tk.bs blib/arch/auto/Tk/Tk.bs 644
cd pTk && make DEFINE="" LIBPERL_A="libperl.a" LINKTYPE="dynamic" OPTIMIZE="-Os" PREFIX="/usr/local" PASTHRU_DEFINE=' ' PASTHRU_INC='-I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 '
Manifying 102 pod documents
Manifying 1 pod document
Manifying 2 pod documents
"/usr/bin/perl" -MExtUtils::Command::MM -e 'cp_nonempty' -- X.bs ../../blib/arch/auto/Tk/X/X.bs 644
"/usr/bin/perl" -MExtUtils::Command::MM -e 'cp_nonempty' -- Xlib.bs ../blib/arch/auto/Tk/Xlib/Xlib.bs 644
"/usr/bin/perl" -MExtUtils::Command::MM -e 'cp_nonempty' -- WinPhoto.bs ../blib/arch/auto/Tk/WinPhoto/WinPhoto.bs 644
Manifying 1 pod document
"/usr/bin/perl" -MExtUtils::Command::MM -e 'cp_nonempty' -- Pixmap.bs ../blib/arch/auto/Tk/Pixmap/Pixmap.bs 644
"/usr/bin/perl" -MExtUtils::Command::MM -e 'cp_nonempty' -- TixGrid.bs ../blib/arch/auto/Tk/TixGrid/TixGrid.bs 644
Manifying 1 pod document
"/usr/bin/perl" -MExtUtils::Command::MM -e 'cp_nonempty' -- Text.bs ../blib/arch/auto/Tk/Text/Text.bs 644
"/usr/bin/perl" -MExtUtils::Command::MM -e 'cp_nonempty' -- TList.bs ../blib/arch/auto/Tk/TList/TList.bs 644
"/usr/bin/perl" -MExtUtils::Command::MM -e 'cp_nonempty' -- Scrollbar.bs ../blib/arch/auto/Tk/Scrollbar/Scrollbar.bs 644
"/usr/bin/perl" -MExtUtils::Command::MM -e 'cp_nonempty' -- Scale.bs ../blib/arch/auto/Tk/Scale/Scale.bs 644
cd zlib && make libz.a "CC=cc  " RANLIB="/usr/bin/ar s"
make[2]: `libz.a' is up to date.
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make  all-am
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all-am'.
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
"/usr/bin/perl" -MExtUtils::Command::MM -e 'cp_nonempty' -- PNG.bs ../blib/arch/auto/Tk/PNG/PNG.bs 644
Manifying 1 pod document
"/usr/bin/perl" -MExtUtils::Command::MM -e 'cp_nonempty' -- NBFrame.bs ../blib/arch/auto/Tk/NBFrame/NBFrame.bs 644
"/usr/bin/perl" -MExtUtils::Command::MM -e 'cp_nonempty' -- Mwm.bs ../blib/arch/auto/Tk/Mwm/Mwm.bs 644
"/usr/bin/perl" -MExtUtils::Command::MM -e 'cp_nonempty' -- Menubutton.bs ../blib/arch/auto/Tk/Menubutton/Menubutton.bs 644
"/usr/bin/perl" -MExtUtils::Command::MM -e 'cp_nonempty' -- Listbox.bs ../blib/arch/auto/Tk/Listbox/Listbox.bs 644
cd jpeg && make libjpeg.a
make[2]: `libjpeg.a' is up to date.
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
"/usr/bin/perl" -MExtUtils::Command::MM -e 'cp_nonempty' -- JPEG.bs ../blib/arch/auto/Tk/JPEG/JPEG.bs 644
Manifying 1 pod document
Manifying 1 pod document
"/usr/bin/perl" -MExtUtils::Command::MM -e 'cp_nonempty' -- InputO.bs ../blib/arch/auto/Tk/InputO/InputO.bs 644
"/usr/bin/perl" -MExtUtils::Command::MM -e 'cp_nonempty' -- IO.bs ../blib/arch/auto/Tk/IO/IO.bs 644
"/usr/bin/perl" -MExtUtils::Command::MM -e 'cp_nonempty' -- HList.bs ../blib/arch/auto/Tk/HList/HList.bs 644
"/usr/bin/perl" -MExtUtils::Command::MM -e 'cp_nonempty' -- Event.bs ../blib/arch/auto/Tk/Event/Event.bs 644
"/usr/bin/perl" -MExtUtils::Command::MM -e 'cp_nonempty' -- Entry.bs ../blib/arch/auto/Tk/Entry/Entry.bs 644
Manifying 3 pod documents
"/usr/bin/perl" -MExtUtils::Command::MM -e 'cp_nonempty' -- Compound.bs ../blib/arch/auto/Tk/Compound/Compound.bs 644
"/usr/bin/perl" -MExtUtils::Command::MM -e 'cp_nonempty' -- Canvas.bs ../blib/arch/auto/Tk/Canvas/Canvas.bs 644
"/usr/bin/perl" -MExtUtils::Command::MM -e 'cp_nonempty' -- PNG.bs ../blib/arch/auto/Tk/PNG/PNG.bs 644
cd zlib && make libz.a "CC=cc  " RANLIB="/usr/bin/ar s"
make[2]: `libz.a' is up to date.
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make  all-am
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all-am'.
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `test_dynamic'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [subdirs-test_dynamic] Error 2
make: *** [subdirs-test_dynamic] Error 2
```

Comment: Can you provide some more lines from the error message?

Comment: Thank you for your response.

I am updating my initial post with the full log of the make test command.

Comment: Hi Gauthier. Thanks for the update. Unfortunately, I am not so familiar with mac os, I am using mostly Linux. But I have an old mac which I now tried for fun installing Tk on.  However, I ran into [this issue](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7022116?start=0&tstart=0).. Hope you can get help from someone more familiar with mac os.

Comment: May be related to https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=106958  I have had to disable tests to get Tk to install on various platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Try it manually, as stated into file INSTALL:
- download Tkxxxxxx.tar.gz from CPAN
- zcat Tkxxxxx.tar.gz | tar xf -
- cd to the directory distribution unpacks to.
- perl Makefile.PL
- make
- make test
if all is OK then sudo make install

Comment: Thank you for your help :-)
Unfortunately I run into the exact same error with this process too...

Comment: Nothing was built?

Comment: find . -iname '*.so' -exec ls -l {} \;

Comment: perl -Mblib basic_demo

Comment: Well, I ran make test and the same error shown.
Regarding your suggestion, I didn't understand what you told me to do, when in the module's directory there is no basic demo file.
Files were created, but for some reason unlike other modules I have installed, it doesn't go through the install process.